# $_FILES[ ][ ] isn't working in php

Tags: php, html, amazon-web-services

This is the PHP file that I made for uploading jpeg images to my server. When I loaded the image file and clicked the 'submit' button, `print_r($_FILES)` is working but all `$_FILES[][]` are not working and page displays `OMG empty!`. Result page and codes are below. Is there any reason for this? My PHP version is 5.5.14, browsers are Chrome, Firefox and web server is AWS EC2.

### Result

```
Array ( [file] => Array ( [name] => catcam.jpeg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpb4hf4d [error] => 0 [size] => 5427 ) ) OMG empty!
```

### Code

```
<?php
if (isset($_FILES)) {
    print_r($_FILES);

    echo $fileName = $_FILES[‘file'][‘name'];
    echo $fileTempName = $_FILES[‘file'][‘tmp_name'];
    echo $fileType = $_FILES[‘file'][‘type'];
    echo $fileSize = $_FILES[‘file'][‘size'];
    echo $fileError = $_FILES[‘file'][‘error'];

    if (isset($fileName)) {
        echo "set!";
    }
    if (empty($fileName)) {
        echo "OMG empty!";
    }
}
?>

<html>
    <body>
        <form action="again.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label for="file">Filename:</label>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like you have some issues with your quotes. You have an opening "fancy" quote on all of your arrays and no closing quote. Is that in the actual source? Ex: `$_FILES[‘file][‘name];`

Comment: Having you used [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) would have told you what's wrong.

Comment: @mtinsley oh that's my fault. Original code is alright.

Comment: If original code is alright, then show the original code; it's misleading. Your `‘` in what you have now, should be `'` and use the error reporting link I gave you to check for errors. Plus, why are you echoing variables?

Comment: @Fred-ii- OMG! it was apostrophe problem! There are 2 kinds of apostrophe, you know, one is ' , and the other looking like comma. I should have used the prior one. t

Comment: Aaahh there you go. Another happy person ;-) glad it worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your (edited) code (still) contains curly quotes `‘` and will break its functionality.

Change it to the following:

```
echo $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
echo $fileTempName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
echo $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];
echo $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
echo $fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];
```

These should have triggered an 500 error in your logs, should you have access to them.

Error reporting would have shown you what was wrong.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.